# Menu java script abre e fecha outras divs

Tags: javascript

Estou com um problema que é simples porém não utilizo `JS` a um tempo então fiquei com um problema.

Estou tendo de criar um menu parecido com o da [amazon](http://www.amazon.com/), porém o site é responsivo e fiz com listas. Porém não ficou bom então estou fazendo com DIVs (caso alguem tenha ideia melhor agradeço) o problema é o seguinte.

Ao clicar em um botão do menu ele abre a `div` pelo `id` do mesmo, porém quando clico em outro ele deveria fechar a que estava aberta mas não consigo fazer fecha-las.

Estou usando o seguinte código para ficar o mais leve possível.

JS

```
$(function(){
    $(".btn-toggle").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        el = $(this).data('element');
        $(el).toggle(); 
    });

});
```

html

```
<div id="menu_drop">
    <ul class="menu_topo">
        <li ><a href="#" ><button type="button" class="btn-toggle" data-element="#minhaDiv">Mídias e Embalagens</button></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><button type="button" class="btn-toggle" data-element="#minhaDiv1">Informática</button></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Eletrônicos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Telefonia</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Papelaria e Escritório</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Cine e Foto</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Utilidades</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Esporte e Lazer</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Brinquedos</a></li>   
     </ul>

</div><!-- menu drop-->
<div id="minhaDiv" class="menu_lado">Conteudo</div>
<div id="minhaDiv1" class="menu_lado">Conteudo1</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma solução elegante (ao meu ver), pode ser alcançada da seguinte maneira:

```js
$(".btn-toggle").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  el = $(this).data('element');
  $(el).toggle();
  $(el).siblings().hide();
});
```

```css
.menu_lado:not(:first-of-type){
      
  /* Construído assim, o primeiro elemento será mostrado quando a página carregar. Se você quiser esconder todos por padrão, é só retirar os pseudo-elementos do seletor */
      
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="menu_drop">
  <ul class="menu_topo">
       
    <!-- Reduzi o html pra leitura ficar mais fácil --> 
         
    <li><a href="#"><button type="button" class="btn-toggle" data-element="#minhaDiv">Mídias e Embalagens</button></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><button type="button" class="btn-toggle" data-element="#minhaDiv1">Informática</button></a></li>   
   </ul>
</div><!-- menu drop-->

<div class="content">
      
  <!-- Envolvi as divs de conteudo em uma div, pra facilitar o acesso via js -->
      
  <div id="minhaDiv" class="menu_lado">Midias e embalagens</div>
  <div id="minhaDiv1" class="menu_lado">Informatica</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Eu esqueci completamente de guardar a variável. Só tem um pequeno detalhe, quando eu clico novamente no menu ele não fecha a que ele mesmo abriu. Tipo Assim: Clica Menu 1 > Abre Div 1 Clica Menu 1 novamente > Fecha Div 1 Clica Menu 1 > Abre Div 1 Clica Menu 2 > Fecha Div 1 e Abre Div 2 TKS!

Comment: @RodrigoB.Silva, Eu já corrigi este detalhe. Rode o código novamente. Troquei `toggle()` por `show()` sem querer

Comment: Por algum motivo não está funcionando quando implemento.
Até copiei o código em outro HTML e não funciona oO'

Comment: Isso está gerando algum erro?

Comment: simplesmente não abre nem fecha, como se não existisse o JS.

Comment: Você inseriu o jquery, certo?

Comment: Sim! heheheheh

O código que o IazyFox postou funciona até ( o problema é que não fecha novamente ao clicar nele), agora o seu só funcionou com o primeiro código postado.

Comment: Curioso, eu testei aqui e está funcionando perfeitamente...

Answer (score 1):

Guarda numa variável global o ultimo aberto e fecha-o sempre que abrires um novo, caso não exista um "ultimo", não o fechas.

```
var ultimo;
    $(function(){
    $(".btn-toggle").click(function(e){
        if (ultimo)
          $(ultimo).toggle();
        e.preventDefault();
        el = $(this).data('element');
        $(el).toggle();
        ultimo = el;
    });
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente.
Eu esqueci completamente de guardar a variável. 

Só tem um pequeno detalhe, quando eu clico novamente no menu ele não fecha a que ele mesmo abriu.

Tipo Assim:

Clica Menu 1 >  Abre Div  1 
Clica Menu 1 novamente > Fecha  Div 1

Clica Menu 1 >  Abre Div  1 
Clica Menu 2 > Fecha  Div 1 e Abre Div 2
TKS!